# adding multiple values in a text box on click of a button

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
        <td><font face="Arial">Answers</font></td>
        <td>
        <div id="answers" >
            <input type="text" name="T2" size="20" id="answer" class="selector">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="+" name="B3" id="btnAnswer" onclick="addAnswers()">
        (click on this button will create another field so you can type content
        for the other answer, this can be done using jquery)<br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="1">Allow this answer to be free text

        </td>
    </tr>
```

function addAnswers(){

```
$('#answers').append('<p class="\selector\">' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>'); }
```

Now I want to get thses values of answers to send it to the server..the no of answers could be 1 to n...

Comment: I tried this function addAnswers(){
 $('#T2').val($('#T2').val() + $(this).text()) ;
 alert("val"+$('#T2').val());
}

Answer (score 0):

> I have to add another answer using jquery...Can any one help?

Check out: `document.createElement` in plain javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

And `$(target).append(element)`: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Using query, grab the first input that's child of your td, and clear its data. You can then user $.append to add it where you want in your markup.

You will also want to create a numerical incrementation for each inputs names (such as the names are t1, t2, t3, etc.), so that they can be parsed through efficiently server-side.

**REVISION**

Here's the HTML markup, slightly modified:

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td><font face="Arial">Answers</font></td>
        <td>
        <div id="answers" >
            <input type="text" name="T1" size="20" class="answer selector">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="+" name="B3" id="btnAnswer">
        (click on this button will create another field so you can type content
        for the other answer, this can be done using jquery)<br>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

With the javascript:

```
$('#btnAnswer').click(function(){
    var new_input = $('input.answer:first').clone();     
    new_input.attr('name', new_input.attr('name').substr(0, new_input.attr('name').length-1) + ($('#answers').children('input').length + 1));
    $('#answers').append(new_input);
});
```

The javascript clones the first input and increments its name.

On the server-side, you will need to increment through the posted variables and check them individually to see if they are set; if they are not set, break from the loop.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdnU/1/).

Comment: can u pls give me the example?

Comment: @ user751564 I am adding it like this                               function addAnswers(){
        $('#answers').append('<p class="\selector\">' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>');                                                           Now How do I an=dd these incrementation for each input?pls reply?

Comment: Your question example is has syntax errors and I'm still uncertain as to what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you revise your questions and fix the code before I can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above, check this:

**html**

```
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial">Answers</font></td>
<td><input name="T2" size="20" type="text" id="answer">
<input value="+" name="B3" type="button" id="btnAnswer">
(click on this button will create another field so you can type content
for the other answer, this can be done using jquery)<br>
<input name="c" value="1" type="checkbox">Allow this answer to be free text
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(function(){
    $('#btnAnswer').on('click', function(){
      $('#answers').append('<p>' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>');
    });
  });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU4te/2/) goes here, please check.

-- EDIT --

Well reminded, `onclick` it not needed anymore, considering `jQuery` is doing the "dirty" work.

Comment: Might as well remove the `onclick="addAnswers()"`, no?

Comment: Yeah, @Vap0r. Actually `onclick` not needed anymore.

Comment: getting this arreo TypeError: $("#btnAnswer").on is not a function

Comment: Also, I think it might be smarter to do a `clone()` operation, that way any potential [Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) issues could be avoided. As an added bonus, this may even allow form serialization for publishing the data. Example shown [at this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU4te/1/).

Comment: @Deepmala did you try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU4te/2/)? Remember `btnAnswer` is the id of your button for example only or you probably not referencing jQuery on your code. Check the abbreviated form `$(function() {});` or `$(document).ready(function(){});` on your code.

Comment: @axcdnt :Thanks for the help... I need t get these values of answers to submit to the server How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Deepmala if this answer is ok and solved your problem, please mark it. For your next doubt, there are some different ways to post your data to server. Search here in SO and you'll find different approaches. We better not change the focus of this subject. New doubts, new questions. Hope you understand.

Comment: @axcdnr I did it onclick and it works..function addAnswersnew(answer){
        $('#answers').append('<p>' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>');
 
}..Thanks!I will post new question for sending it to server.

Comment: Yeah man! Nice @Deepmala, just don't forget to mark the best answer to make this issue solved. ;D